# what's wrong with my batch file? Syntax error?

Tags: batch-file

I'm making an offline skin changer for minecraft at the local Community Center using a resource pack. I'm having problems with:

```
if exist %AppData%\.minecraft\resoursepacks\Skins\pack.mcmeta (
goto :StartSkinChanger
)else (
copy BackupFiles %AppData%\.minecraft\resourcepacks /E
)
```

It says there's a syntax error. Can somebody please help?

Comment: you missed a space between `)` and `else`. (is it really "resour**s**epacks"?)

Comment: ... thanks for telling me about the missing space, and for my accidental typo, meant to type resourcepacks.

Comment: did it solve your problem?

Comment: Plus you need to quote all your paths to handle paths with spaces:  E.g.,  `if exist "%AppData%\.minecraft\..."`

Comment: You need quote all your paths And Try `) ELSE (`